# Jetty spikes in response time

Tags: https, jetty, end-of-life

The normal response time (GET request) amounts to around 50-100ms, but randomly on average every 10th request takes 1-1.5 seconds.

This is independent from the request library, server or network used, also in Chrome timing tab this behaviour is easily visible.

Jetty version used is 9.4.7.v20170914.

Can I do anything from client side?

Sending 2 requests at the same time or resending one if takes too long has no effect, both will resolve in 1-1.5 seconds.

Comment: Jetty 9.x is now at End of Community Support - see https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958 - You should be using Jetty 10 or Jetty 11 or Jetty 12 at this point in time. (All of which have updates to the networking code specifically to address changes made in Chrome over the years)